# Java Interface - Fatal Flaw

Tags: java, interface, casting

Suppose we have an interface `A`, being implemented by class `B`:

```
public interface A {
    public int getValueForName(String name);
}

public class B implements A {

    public int getValueForName(String name) {
        //implementation
    }

    public String getNameForValue(int value) {
        //implementation
    }

}
```

If programmers consistently use type `A` every time an instance of `B` is referred to, then any method, say `getNameForValue()`, defined in `B` but not specified in `A` is hidden and cannot be accessed by any code holding a reference of type `A`.

It seems that there is a fatal flaw with this approach. How can a piece of code referring to an instance of `B` (with type `A`) access `getNameForValue()`?

Comment: Why would any piece of code that wants `A` need to execute `m`.  `A` by it's nature explicitly excludes `m` from the knowledge of anybody wanting `A` - that's the point.  Any one wanting `A` should never care about anything other then what `A` defines...

Comment: Whoa, whoa, why was this put on hold?  There's a perfectly reasonable answer to this, and I feel like it stems from a misunderstanding of what interfaces provide.  [EDIT]:  Meta discussion [can be found here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201606/175248).

Comment: @MadProgrammer: How does that explicitly excludes `m` because if we are writing a method in class `B` than it is supposed to be defined in interface `A`. Right ?

Comment: @bddesai89 I was trying to find a means by which to word this.  But anything that expects `A` only expects what `A` defines, it should NEVER care about `B` or what `B` defines BEYOND the contact it has with `A`, therefore, `A` explicitly excludes anything not defined by `A` from the knowledge of those want to work with `A`...

Comment: When a piece of code refers to `Type A`, it is refering to `Type A`. It may be a `class B, C or Z`. B might have `m`, but other implementations or A may not. So trying to access `m` may cause the `downfall of civilisation`, or  cause your program to crash, either way its bad. We use interfaces to restrict revelation so our api is smaller, simpler and cleaner. Having to reveal everything all the time makes life more difficult for everyone. If you want B refer to B. In the older times casting was necessary all over the place, generics greatly  reduces the need but does not eliminate it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer : Oh Thanks. And I thought it has something to do with casting :P

Comment: @BevynQ : Yeah the program should crash but here its working fine.

Comment: @BevynQ It will either cause a compilation error or a runtime class cast exception...

Comment: `interface A
{

}

class B implements A
{
 void m()
 {
  System.out.println("Hello World");
 }
}

class seven
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
   B b = new B();
   b.m();
 }
}`
This works absolutely good. Check out yourself @BevynQ

Comment: @bddesai89:  If you want to edit that code into the question, that'd be fine.  I had created some dummy methods and classes to make the question a little bit clearer.

Comment: @bddesai89 your code behaves as expected the situation it will fail is  `A c = new C();((B)c).m();` `throwing a ClassCastException`. To avoid that we do `if(c instanceof B) then cast otherwise do not`. It is better to not cast if it is not necessary. However sometimes it cannot be avoided.

Comment: The code in your comment compiles and runs fine, but what does that code have to do with your question? It would be relevant if it was `main(String args[]) { A b = new B(); b.m(); }`. This does not compile because `b` is only known to implement `A`, not be specifically a `B` object.

Comment: @TedHopp: Yes, now I get it so we need to downcast the object `b` like `((B)b).m();` and that will work good. Thanks man (y)

Answer (score 3):

The *real* flaw is that the contract of the interface isn't being respected.  If I'm using the interface, I shouldn't care about any other methods except those defined in the interface.

If the interface does not define the method that I want to work with, then either the interface needs to be updated to accommodate that new method, or I need to use a different interface.

Take, for instance, [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).  If I have an instance that is bound to the contract of `Collection`, then I have access to an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).  However, I know that the elements I'm getting back are of type `List`, and I want to make use of the [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) instead, which is more powerful.

The problem is that **`Collection` does not define any way for me to access a `ListIterator`**.  So, I have but one option (since I can't just go and update the `Collection` interface needlessly):  use the `List` interface instead.

If you run into this scenario in your own code, your interfaces are not supporting the methods that they need to be.  Add that support at the **interface** level *instead* of at the **instance** level.

Comment: `interface A { } 
class B implements A { void m() { System.out.println("Hello World"); } } class seven { public static void main(String args[]) { B b = new B(); b.m(); } }`    Compile and run this program. Works absolutely good

Comment: @bddesai89:  Yes, I would expect that to work - you're using the concrete type which has access to `m()`.

Answer (score 1):

> How can a piece of code referring to an instance of B (with type A) access getNameForValue()?

By casting the instance to type B.

One of the purposes of an interface is to define methods that are common to two or more types.  That doesn't mean that you're going to define interface methods for every possible combination of every possible type, but only those methods that are common to all types that you wish to expose via the interface.

So by definition, having an instance of the interface type presumes that there may be methods in the original type which you are not going to have access to through the interface.  That's just how it works.

Another reason you might have an interface is to specify a capability.  So if a class is Iterable, that means it can be iterated.  If I'm trying to get an Iterable instance, I care about the methods in the class that implement Iterable's methods, but I don't care about any other methods, because they don't have anything to do with the Iterable capability.

In short, it's a feature, not a flaw.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it from a more real life example.  If I am blindfolded and you tell me that there is a household pet in front of me what can I do with it?  Probably pet it would be all.  Now if you tell me it is a hamster I would also be able to put it in a wheel for it to run around (my cat on the other hand would not go for that idea).

When you have a variable declared as an interface (or a higher level class), such as your `A` it is the same as the household pet in the example above.  As such not all of the methods will be accessible to you.

To know if it is a hamster, or a `B` you must remove the blindfold.  In the case of Java that would mean calling `instanceof` and then casting the variable to a `B`.  You need the `instanceof` to make sure that the cast is safe.  Unless, of course, you know that the thing is a `B`, in which case you may want to actually declare it to be a `B` to begin with instead.

If you find yourself casting you probably have done something "wrong" with your design.  It is rare, since Java got generics, to have to cast anymore.

Comment: You have combined hamsters and cats into a concrete Java example that makes a ton of sense.  +1.